# How to publish ASP.NET MVC application on Linux hosting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linux, hosting

I am created ASP.NET MVC application but buyed one Linux hosting(Globehosting.com). SO How can I publish my asp.net mvc application on linux. I think they use CGI to deploy website.

Comment: Is the project .NET Core?

Comment: @BrunoL. No MVC 4

Comment: @DouglasThomas thanks man It's very helpful

Comment: @user7013033 You're welcome. Glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, you can't.  ASP.net is a Microsoft product and must be hosted on a Windows server with IIS (Internet Information Service)

Most hosting providers offer both a Linux and Windows server option.  And if you've already purchased the Linux server, you should be able to either call them and have it migrated to Windows, or do it online through their website.

Comment: as of today (2017) you have asp.net core, mono-project to host .net application on linux, mac etc.